# How to use Post Install Script to enable Quotes and Order object

Tags: apex

Is it possible to enable the `Quotes` and `Order` objects using a Post Install Script and, if so, how?

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is possible.

Use the following code :-

```
 HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
    request = new HttpRequest();
    request.setEndpoint('https://ap2.salesforce.com/services/Soap/m/31.0');
    request.setMethod('POST');  
    request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
    request.setHeader('SOAPAction', 'update');               
    String b = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';
            b += '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">';
            b += '<soapenv:Header>';
            b += '<ns1:SessionHeader soapenv:mustUnderstand="0" xmlns:ns1="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">';
            b += '<ns1:sessionId>' + UserInfo.getSessionId() + '</ns1:sessionId>';
            b += '</ns1:SessionHeader>';
            b += '</soapenv:Header>';
            b += '<soapenv:Body>';

            b += '<update xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">';
            b += '<UpdateMetadata>';
            b += '<currentName>QuoteSettings</currentName>';

            b += '<metadata xsi:type="ns2:QuoteSettings" xmlns:ns2="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">';

            b += '<fullName>QuoteSettings</fullName>';
            b += '<enableQuote>true</enableQuote>';

            b += '</metadata>';
            b += '</UpdateMetadata>';
            b += '</update>';
            b += '</soapenv:Body>';
            b += '</soapenv:Envelope>';
        request.setBody(b);
        request.setCompressed(false);

    String body = (new Http()).send(request).getBody();
    system.debug('response'+body);
```

Comment: I can not use this in post install script right? @abhinav

Comment: Yes, because we cannot get the sessionId in the post install script.